# create UILabel with dynamic height according to size of label text

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

How to create a `uilabel` in swift with dynamic height so that line breaks automatically.

```
label = UILabel();
var str = " khduhfi8wde fwei9jfriuwqef iwfiuwqef iefiedf ejfiejfi9e      eihjfiefi8e eifiejh";
label.frame = CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 100);
label.text = str;
view.addSubview(label);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface Builder, set a high priority to the width of the label, then set the hugging priority to high.

Also, do not forget to set numberOfLines to 0.

Text will then display with dynamic height.